# Character encoding

Tags: html

While Iam copying text phrase from notepad++ (phrase include spaces, copyright symbol (©), registered symbol (®) etc) to the html, after saving the html page, it is showing weird characters like Â instead of space and other also.
On my html page, Iam having charset under meta tag like charset=UTF-8.
Issue is occurring while copying text from notepad++ only.
Please assist me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML (as far as I know), you should always use HTML entities for representing characters like `©` (which is provided as `&copy;`). Here is a complete list of [HTML Entities](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)

Comment: Yes this is right..but what can I do if Iam copying text from notepad++. This issue in only appearing when Iam copying any text which has these specials chars.

Comment: I would suggest **NOT TO COPY ANY CODE** but rather rewriting them. Copying text would remove all formatting as well. As far as these special characters go, you can do a FIND+REPLACE in notepad to replace these characters with the respective HTML entities and then copy the same.

Comment: THis is OK from developer prospective ie rewriting, but how to do so If a end user is placing any text copied from np++ which has such characters and now Its is require to restrict these characters.

Comment: In that case, the application should have proper placeholders for end-users to copy just text and paste in designated areas (or in config/properties files). For e.g. Copyright message can be broken into two parts: The text before and after ©. They can be substituted by end users later (not within the code possibly but in your externalized files).